# Firestore rules not working like they should. Path and values are correct, but still saying invalid permissions on read

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

So I have these firestore rules here:

```
match /Customers/{customerId} {
  allow read, update, create, delete: if request.auth != null && get(/databases/$(database)/documents/Users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.businessId in resource.data.businessIds || request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == resource.data.uid || request.auth != null && get(/databases/$(database)/documents/Users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.businessId == resource.data.businessId || request.auth != null && get(/databases/$(database)/documents/Users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.customerId == resource.data.customerId;

    match /ServiceLocations/{ServiceLocationId} {
    allow read, update, create, delete: request.auth != null && get(/databases/$(database)/documents/Users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.businessId == resource.data.businessId;
  }
}
```

And for some reason when I am calling read on /ServiceLocations/{ServiceLocationId} inside the /Customers/{customerId} hierarchy I am getting invalid permissions. But I am confused because the path and values are correct. I am able to read the customerId document fine so there is no issue there, but specifically I cant read the serviceLocationId documents which is a document inside the ServiceLocations subcollection inside the customerId document.

`get(/databases/$(database)/documents/Users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.businessId`

is a valid path which returns a businessId.

`resource.data.businessId`

and businessId is a valid field inside the serviceLocationId document and both values do infact equal eachother. Yet it is still returning false.

Attached are two images showing the "Users" document of the user I am sending the request from which includes the businessId field, and the serviceLocationId document I am trying to read from, which also includes the businessId field. And as you can see both values do infact match and the paths are correct.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJNPN.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8sgM.png

Here is an example of one of the requests being called invalid:

```
db.collection("Customers")
      .doc(selectedCustomerData.customerId)
      .collection("ServiceLocations")
      .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
```

Am I just doing something wrong? It makes no sense to me. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the exact code that you think should work but it getting rejected by your rules. In there also make sure to show how your code satisfies the requirements of your rules, i.e. log the UID and other values that your rules check.

Comment: It happening anywhere I try and access the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect this is a case where the [security rules cannot filter your data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#rules_are_not_filters) for you.

Specifically, I think the rules may not be able to enforce this requirement on their own:

```
get(/databases/$(database)/documents/Users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.businessId == 
resource.data.businessId;
```

Try passing a filter in the query where you also pass the user's business ID (`.where('businessId', '==', 'The business ID of the user')`), or pass the business ID as a [custom claim](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims) rather then looking it up in a document.

Comment: lmao why did this fix it I am so confused. Every single serviceLocationId doc has the buisinessId field with the same value inside the customer since all the service locations belong to the same customer which belongs to the same businessId.

Comment: If every value is the same why would you need to filter it. Oh well, I guess atleast I can fix the issues now lol.

Comment: It also happens with .get() and its making me also filter with .where which also makes no damn sense lol.

Comment: plus I have another documents with subcollections and everything and that does not require any .wheres for the rules to allow it. I am hella confused why the .where helps here.

Comment: After some research I understand a bit better. I appreciate the help sir you are a legend.